# Use VBA to review all CommandButtons

Tags: vba, excel

I know this should be simple....I have an Excel spreadsheet that has some number of Commandbuttons (CommandButton1, CommandButton2, ...).   I want to loop through these buttons in a for statement without using a case statement to determine which button to use.  I have tried the following:

```
Dim cButtons(0 to 5) as CommandButton

cButtons(0) = Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1
cButtons(1) = Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton2
'etc...
```

but that gives an error "Object variable or With block variable not set".  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try to use `Set` keyword: `Set cButtons(0) = Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton1`

Comment: Thanks much!  This is the easiest solution.  Being new to VBA, I didn't know how to store a reference to the object, like int* a in c++.

Comment: just remember every time you want to assign _object_ to variable, use `Set`:)

Answer (score 1):

Why not ignore setting the `Object` at all if it's a loop you can do this unless you need a direct reference to the object.

```
For i=1 To Sheet1.Shapes.Count
    Sheet1.Shapes.Item(i) 'Do Something with it
Next i
```

If you do need a direct reference you can use the name

```
Sheet1.Shapes.Item("CommandButton1") 'Do Something
```